# HeaderText value in a repeater control in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, repeater

How can I set the column header text value for a repeater control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the `<HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate>`

Note though that the Repeater control is completely custom to your own HTML and does not render like a GridView or DataGrid

Comment: How do you mean a repeater does not render like a Gridview or DataGrid?

Comment: Well in a GridView or DataGrid, it displays tabular data. e.g. renders as a table with the thead, tbody, etc... It is easy to bind data to a column and give it header text. In a Repeater you will need to build the HeaderTemplate yourself.